# If a creature would die from an equipment unattaching, does that creature die with the effects of the equipment?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Grafted Wargear states: Equipped creature gets +3/+2 and whenever [Grafted Wargear](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Grafted%20Wargear) becomes unattached from a creature, sacrifice that creature.

If I have Grafted Wargear attached to a 1/1 creature and attach it to another creature in order to get an easy die trigger, will that first creature die as a 4/3 or will it die with its base power and toughness?

Very important distinction for my [Shirei, Shizo's Caretaker](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Shirei%2C%20Shizo%27s%20Caretaker) deck.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**It would die without the equipment buff. In your case it would die as a 1/1 and trigger Shirei, Shizo's Caretaker.**

As soon as you unattach the Wargear, the creature it had equipped loses the power/toughness bonus. The ability that forces you to sacrifice the creature is a *triggered ability*, where unattaching the equipment is the trigger for that ability in the first place. A triggered ability goes on the stack and can be responded to much like a spell, so by the time it does resolve and you have to actually perform the sacrifice, the P/T bonus is long gone.

> 113.3c Triggered abilities have a trigger condition and an effect. They are written as “[Trigger condition], [effect],” and include (and usually begin with) the word “when,” “whenever,” or “at.” Whenever the trigger event occurs, the ability is put on the stack the next time a player would receive priority and stays there until it’s countered, it resolves, or it otherwise leaves the stack. See rule 603, “Handling Triggered Abilities.”

Comment: For the sake of the OP, this is different in the case of, oh let's say Skullclamp, correct?  The 1/1 creature dies as a result of having 0 toughness, dies as a 2/0, and does not trigger Shirei?

Comment: Correct, if the creature dies while the equipment is still attached, its last known information (the state in which it last existed on the battlefield) is used, and it would show a 2/0 died, not triggering Sihrei.

Comment: @DenisS With Skullclamp, the creature loses toughness from a continuous effect, and then dies from a state based action. None of that uses the stack. With Grafter Wargear, the sacrifice effect is triggered and does use the stack.

Comment: This answers OP's specific question in the body but not the general question posed in the title. What if the creature had taken non-lethal damage but unattaching the equipment caused the creatures toughness to be reduced, which makes the previously non-lethal damage, lethal damage? I believe it would have it's P/T without the equipment's bonus for any calculation but I'm not sure as the answer here focuses a bit on the Triggered Ability's impact on the process.

Comment: @DavidJacobsen The question body gives no hint that the title posed that more general question. OP made it clear that the question was specifically about the Shirei/Wargear combo, making a bunch of 1/1 creatures and using the Wargear as a repeatable sac outlet. And just to answer your question, yes, if the creature died to marked damage after unattaching the Wargear, it would still die as a 1/1, except as an SBA instead of to the Wargear ability.